# Finding all permutations and calling a function on results in R

Tags: r

Need to write a function `permn(m,n,FUN)` that finds all permutations of m of size n, and returns a vector of values returned by calling FUN on each permutation, but struggling to figure out how to call FUN on each one.

Since we don't care about efficiency, I decided to first compute all the permutations using the `permutations()` function, and then pass the vector of permutations into FUN. However, this only works in cases where FUN doesn't require accessing a specific index of the vector.

```
permn <- function(m, n, FUN=NULL) {
  result <- c()
  if (length(m) == 1) {
    p <- permutations(length(1:m),n,1:m)
  } else {
    p <- permutations(length(m),n,m)
  }

  result <- FUN(p)
  return(result)
}
```

If I do the following, `permn(4,2,function(x){2*x})`, FUN is applied to each element in the matrix, and I get the correct output, a 12x2 matrix. However, passing a function such as `first <- function(z) z[1]` which is supposed to return the first element of each permutation, only returns a single element. For example, calling 
`permn(7:10,2,first)` is supposed to return `[1] 7 7 7 8 8 8 9 9 9 10 10 10` from a matrix that looks like

`[1,]  7  8`

`[2,]  7  9`

`[3,]  7  10`

`[4,]  8  7`

...

but instead returns `7`. How can I make it so that FUN is applied to each permutation in the vector?

Comment: Are you using `permutations()` from `gtools` package?

Comment: @andrew_reece yes

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`purrr::map`](https://purrr.tidyverse.org/reference/map.html) or base R `sapply`:

```
first <- function(z) purrr::map_dbl(z[,1], ~.x[1])

# alternate
# first <- sapply(z[,1], function(x) x[1])

permn(7:10, 2, first)
#  7  7  7  8  8  8  9  9  9 10 10 10
```

**Update** per OP comments
If you need to keep `first()` as-is, just wrap with `map` inside `permn`, like this:

```
first <- function(z) z[1]

permn <- function(m, n, FUN=NULL) {
  result <- c()
  if (length(m) == 1) {
    p <- permutations(length(1:m),n,1:m)
  } else {
    p <- permutations(length(m),n,m)
  }

  result <- purrr::map_dbl(p[,1], FUN)
  return(result)
}

permn(7:10, 2, first)
#  7  7  7  8  8  8  9  9  9 10 10 10
```

Comment: I can't edit the function calls, it has to work for `first <- function(z) z[1]`

Comment: you can just wrap `FUN` with `map`.

Comment: it doesn't work for `permn(4,2,function(x){2*x})` anymore.